# How do you write a LINQ query that filters a sub table to a specific time period and sums the results of the sub table?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, subquery, left-join

That is the most efficient way to perform a left outer join in LINQ if I must do the following...

- Filter Table 2 by a beginning and ending date.
- All rows in Table 1 must remain, even if the filtering of Table 2 returns no rows.
- The result must be grouped so that the columns from Table 2 get summed.

For example (example code variable names changed for propietary reasons), supposed I have a database with two tables.  Table 1 has a list of doors with a building code, door ID and current status (open or closed) - the building code and door ID are the primary key.  Table 2 has a list of events for all doors (an event is an opening or closing) plus a timestamp.  So the columns are building code, door ID, timestamp, opening, closing.  Opening and closing are integers with a 1 in the column for the appropriate event.  There is a foreign key relationship between the two tables on the building code and door ID.

For my query I need to return a list of all the unique doors with the current door status and a sum of all the opening and closing events for a selected time period. *An entry must be returned for each door, even if no events occured during the selected time period.*

Below is the best LINQ code I could come up with.  It works, but it seems really inefficient and hard to understand.  How would you make it more efficient and easier to understand?

```
var query = 
    from doors in Context.Doors
    join fevents in
        (
        from events in db.Events
        where events.TimeStamp >= date1 && events.TimeStamp <= date2
        select new { events.BuildingCode, events.DoorID, events.TimeStamp, events.Opening, events.Closing }
        )
    on new { doors.BuildingCode, doors.DoorID } equals { fevents.BuildingCode, fevents.DoorID }
    into g1
    from c in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group c by new
    {
        doors.BuildingCode,
        doors.DoorID,
        doors.DoorStatus
    } into g2
    select new
    {
        BuildingCode = g2.Key.BuildingCode,
        DoorID = g2.Key.DoorID,
        Status = g2.Key.DoorStatus
        NumOpenings = g2.Sum(i => (i == null ? 0 : i.Opening)),
        NumClosings = g2.Sum(i => (i == null ? 0 : i.Closing))
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is slightly easier to read

```
var query = 
    from doors in Context.Doors
    from c in db.Events
                .Where(events => doors.BuildingCode == events.BuildingCode)
                .Where(events => doors.DoorID == events.DoorID)
                .Where(events => events.TimeStamp >= date1 && events.TimeStamp <= date2)
                .Select(events => new { events.BuildingCode, events.DoorID, events.TimeStamp, events.Opening, events.Closing })
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
    group c by new
    {
        doors.BuildingCode,
        doors.DoorID,
        doors.DoorStatus
    } into g2
    select new
    {
        BuildingCode = g2.Key.BuildingCode,
        DoorID = g2.Key.DoorID,
        Status = g2.Key.DoorStatus
        NumOpenings = g2.Sum(i => (i == null ? 0 : i.Opening)),
        NumClosings = g2.Sum(i => (i == null ? 0 : i.Closing))
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @aducci.  Very helpful.  It got me thinking about the problem in a different way.  I've posted my slightly different answer as a reference for others.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @adducci helped me come up with a slightly different solution that I think is even more readable, albeit possibly less efficient.

```
var query = 
    from doors in Context.Doors
    from events in doors.Events
                        .Where(i => i.TimeStamp >= date1 && i.TimeStamp <= date2)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { doors, events }
    by doors into g
    select new 
    { 
        BuildingCode = g.Key.BuildingCode,
        DoorID = g.Key.DoorID,
        Status = g.Key.DoorStatus,
        NumOpenings = g.Sum(i => (i.events == null ? 0 : i.events.Opening)),
        NumClosings = g.Sum(i => (i.events == null ? 0 : i.events.Closing))
    };
```

Note that an alternative method for filtering by date would be directly in the summing function, as below, but this is *much less efficient* since **all** records would be retrieved from the database and then filtered locally.

```
...
//from events in doors.Events
//                    .Where(i => i.TimeStamp >= date1 && i.TimeStamp <= date2)
//                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
from events in doors.Events
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
...
NumOpenings = g.Sum(i => (i.events == null ? 0 : (i.events.Timestamp >= date1 && i.events.TimeStamp <= date2) ? i.events.Opening : 0)),
NumClosings = g.Sum(i => (i.events == null ? 0 : (i.events.Timestamp >= date1 && i.events.TimeStamp <= date2) ? i.events.Closing : 0))
...
```